# Windows phone7: Restrict inserting certain keys for textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my windows phone7(silverlight) application I have to restrict inserting symbols for a textbox. Basically I need **only** to allow inserting **alphanumeric** characters.

So as the first step I added

`InputScope="AlphanumericHalfWidth"` and then `InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"`.

But in both the situations, the keyboard shows and allows to enter the following characters and many more. `@ # $ % & % ( ) !`

Therefore I just implemented the following logic in the text box `KeyDown` event

```
    if (!( (e.PlatformKeyCode >= 48 && e.PlatformKeyCode <= 57) || (e.PlatformKeyCode >= 65 && e.PlatformKeyCode <= 90) || (e.PlatformKeyCode >= 97 && e.PlatformKeyCode <= 122)))
    {
         e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But the thing is It still allows to enter the following characters for the textbox. `@ # $ % & % ( ) !`

Can't figure out how exactly I have to achieve this. If someone can guide me a way to restrict all the other characters except alphanumeric to be inserted for the textbox, would really appreciate. Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because PlatformKeyCode are not ASCII values, which you are trying to handle.

Use TextChanged event handler:

```
private void bla_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bla.Text = Regex.Replace(bla.Text, @"[^\w\s]", string.Empty);
}
```

where bla is the textbox name.

Comment: Thank you very much igrali. Yes this works for me.... But one thing I am not clear. Do you know what exactly it pass by the "e.PlatformKeyCode" in the "KeyDown" Event. As you say, its not exactly return the corresponding ASCII value.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but you can find more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.platformkeycode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regex check to validate that (a bit cleaner than your current approach) and you'll have to disregard the last char, i.e. remove it from the text in your textbox

Comment: Hi AD .Net. I tested with RegEx as well. The thing is "e.PlatformKeyCode" returns 50 for both '2' and '@'. Like that 51 for '3' and '#' etc. So there is no way to identify it is 3 or # the user entered... That is the problem